# Visual Studio deployment doesn't activate SharePoint feature

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, claims-based-identity, sharepoint-feature

I have a simple SharePoint project with one farm-scoped feature. The feature contains no modules; it just refers to an `SPClaimProviderFeatureReceiver`-derived class which in turn points to an `SPClaimProvider`-derived class.

When I tell the project to deploy, it does successfully add the assembly to the GAC, and does successfully create Feature.xml within a folder in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES`, and gives this output:

```
------ Build started: Project: xxx, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  xxx -> E:\xxx\bin\AnyCPU\Debug\xxx.dll
  Successfully created package at: E:\xxx\xxx.wsp
------ Deploy started: Project: xxx, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Active Deployment Configuration: Default
Run Pre-Deployment Command:
  Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not specified.
Recycle IIS Application Pool:
  Skipping application pool recycle because no matching package on the server was found.
Retract Solution:
  Skipping package retraction because no matching package on the server was found.
Add Solution:
  Adding solution 'xxx.wsp'...
  Deploying solution 'xxx.wsp'...
Activate Features:
  No features in this solution were activated.
Run Post-Deployment Command:
  Skipping deployment step because a post-deployment command is not specified.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The deployed `Feature.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
   Title="xxx"
   AutoActivateInCentralAdmin="TRUE"
   Description="xxx" 
   Id="063aae98-029f-4c01-a20e-15b6c8576bc8"
   ReceiverAssembly="xxx, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6e7f8ba8e1265a7f"
   ReceiverClass="xxx" Scope="Farm" />
```

I'm concerned that it says that no features were activated. The WSP does show up in Central Administration Solution Management, but says that it "isn't deployed", and the feature doesn't show up in Manage Farm Features. When I click on Deploy in the web interface, it says "The solution was successfully deployed" (Why didn't VS do this??). But after that the feature still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

In VS solution explorer, right click on project >> select properties >> select sharepoint tab
Here you have different 'Active deployment configuration'. make sure you have selected appropriate configuration from drop down list. you can modify and view steps of each configuration.

Comment: The active deployment configuration is set to "default". Its deployment steps are "run pre-deployment command", "recycle IIS application pool", "retract solution", "add solution", "activate features", and "run post-deployment command". But clearly, the "activate features" step is not working correctly.

Comment: Same problem as @Reinderien - it's not activating the feature for some reason. I'm using a Timer Job, so I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S) article which says, set `Activate on Default` to `False` and then manually activate against the Web Application. (Not entirely sure why).

Comment: I'm still having this same problem as well with our SharePoint 2013 implementation and Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this kind of error while deploying your solutions to sharepoint environment, ensure that your project is not a sandboxed solution.

Click on your project, go to properties window in Visual Studio and change the value of Sandboxed Solution from true to false. Rebuild your project and deploy.

Answer (score -2):

skipping pre and post deployment command is only a warning because you haven't specified any command for these steps.
in VS SharePoint tab (see Rahil answer on how to get there), you have 2 text boxes for writing your pre and post commands